# DIV element does not cover all of its content

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with the div on my page. It's the only one I have, and it covers the middle of my page. With a few tweaks in CSS, I made it go all the way down.

The problem though, is that the video(which is inside the div element), is sneaking out like so:

[image]

Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" media="screen" />
    <title>Arthur</title>
    <meta content="text/html" charset="windows-1251">
    </head>
<Body background="Images/background2.jpg">
<A Href="main.html"><IMG class="imgborder" src="Images/button.png" align="left"      height="50"></A>
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color:black; width:60%; margin-left: auto ; margin-right: auto ;">

<center><img width="60%" src="Images/logo2.png"></center>
<BR><BR>
<center><img class="imgborder" height="300" src="Images/muller.jpg"></center>
<Font size="5" color="crimson" face="Calibri">

<Center><P align="justify">... </P>

<P align="justify">...</P>

<P align="justify">...</P></Font></Center>



<Center><iframe width="640" height="360" src="..." frameborder="5" 
allowfullscreen></iframe></Center>
<Font size="5" color="crimson" face="Calibri"><P>Thomas Muller</P></font>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS:

```css
@charset"utf-8";
/* CSS Document*/
/*This section is for links*/
a:link {
    font-weight:normal;
    color:crimson
}
a:visited {
    font-weight:normal;
    color:Crimson;
}
a:hover {
    font-weight:bold;
    color: Royalblue;
    font-variant:small-caps;
}
/*This section is for a paragraph section*/
p {
    font-style:normal;
    font-size:18px;
}
blue {
    color:crimson;
}
/*This section is for the image's black border.*/
.imgborder {
    border-color: crimson;
    border:thick;
    border-style:outset;
}
.body {
    background-color: #0000FF;
}
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 990px;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#navigation {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 990px;
    height: 55px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#bottom Half {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 990px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #4d3c37;
}
div {
    /* set div to full width and height */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
p {
    margin-left:2cm;
    margin-right:2cm;
}
```

Comment: I think your main problem is actually that you're mixing deprecated HTML with tags you've invented, and haven't nested them properly.

Comment: This HTML! was last seen in 1998

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I can think of is manually tweaking the black frame's height, or perhaps adding a

```
overflow: hidden;
```

property to the frame (in your rather difficult-to-understand tag system, I believe it would be `<Center>`).

Right now, the `<iframe>` element is *overflowing* from its parent container (the black box). By specifying a height for this box, you can control the size.

By specifying `overflow: hidden`, you can hide the box's overflow - thus doing one of two things:

1. Hiding anything that leaks out of the box, preventing elements that are larger than the box's size to show parts that will seem "unbound" by the container's edges
2. If the elements are chosen properly with semantic HTML, many elements that are not bound by `height` and `width` will automatically size themselves to fit their contents

Another possible solution would be to specify `position: relative` and/or `float: none` for both the container and its children, which sometimes solves the problem.

To emphasize again, it's difficult for us to *test* and debug the code you've given us because it is effectively out of date.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it's difficult to understand(new to HTML, could use some advice).

Comment: Your HTML is not up to par with modern standards (see http://www.w3.org/html/ and http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) - thus it is difficult to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Use inherit for the styles of the video. Like display style attribute can be 'inherit', as well as height and width.

Comment: How exactly do I use inherit?

Comment: style='display:inherit;' width='inherit'