# DIV element not going all the way down to the bottom

Tags: css, html

I have an issue with the div on my page. It's the only one I have, and it covers the middle of my page. With a few tweaks in CSS, I made it go all the way down.

The problem though, is that the video(which is inside the div element), is sneaking out like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xybem.jpg

Here's the html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" media="screen" />
    <title>Arthur</title>
    <meta content="text/html" charset="windows-1251">
</head>
<Body background="Images/background2.jpg">
    <A Href="main.html"><IMG class="imgborder" src="Images/button.png" align="left" height="50"></A>
    <div id="wrapper" style="background-color:black; width:60%; margin-left: auto ; margin-right: auto ;">

        <img class="center" width="60%" src="Images/logo2.png">
        <BR>
        <img class="center imgborder" height="300" src="Images/muller.jpg">


        <P>...</P>

        <P>...</P>

        <P>...</P></Font><

        <iframe class="center" width="500" height="300" src="..." frameborder="5" 
                allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

</body>

</html>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document*/

/*This section is for links*/
a:link
{
    font-weight:normal; color:crimson
}
a:visited
{
    font-weight:normal; color:Crimson;
}
a:hover
{
    font-weight:bold; color: Royalblue; font-variant:small-caps;
}
/*This section is for a paragraph section*/
p {
    font-style:normal; font-size:18px;
}
blue {
    color:crimson;
}
/*This section is for the image's black border.*/
.imgborder {
    border-color: crimson; border:thick; border-style:outset;
}
.body
{
    background-color: #0000FF;
}
html {
    height:100%;
}
body{
    height:100%;
    background-image:url('Images/background2.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
}
}
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 990px;
    height:100%;
    overflow:scroll;
    position:relative;
}

#navigation {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 990px;
    height: 55px;
    background-color: #fff;

}

#bottomHalf {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 990px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #4d3c37;


}
div { /* set div to full width and height */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
p {
    margin-left:2cm; margin-right:2cm; font-family:"calibri"; color:crimson; font-size:16; text-align:justify;
}
table {
    color:crimson;
}
.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
img.center { 
    display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; 
}
iframe.center {
    display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; 
}
```

Comment: Please do not [repost your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377003/div-element-does-not-cover-all-of-its-content).

Comment: duplicate of your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377003/div-element-does-not-cover-all-of-its-content

Comment: I edited the html and css.

Comment: You can edit your question. Otherwise You will always put new question instead of edit?

Comment: Could you possibly put a link to a live-site in the comments here?

Comment: Alas, it isn't online at the moment.

Comment: you can set `display:table-cell` for your div, but it can cause another issues. And yeah, div cant be 100% height as a block element. Use JS or JQ lib to achieve your goal